# select vs distinct vs uniq?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, padrino

I am confused by Ruby's ActiveRecord uniq method. I am using it to try to get back an array of complete objects, not just a particular field.

In my Padrino app script, which saves newspaper names and scores as Score objects, the uniq method by attribute on an ActiveRecord Relation is not working, and neither is distinct, with or without SQL syntax. Can anyone explain what is going on?

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.from_today
        self.where('created_at > ?', Date.today)
    end
end


scores = Score.from_today
scores.class      
=> Score::ActiveRecord_Relation 

scores.first
=> #<Score id: 123, score: -2.55, source: "Mail", created_at: "2016-08-11 04:29:24", updated_at: "2016-08-11 04:29:24">

scores.map(&:source) 
=> ["Mail", "Guardian", "Telegraph", "Independent", "Express", "Mail"]

scores.uniq(:source).count 
=> 6

scores.distinct(:source).count
=> 6

scores.select('distinct (SOURCE)').count
=> 5    #AHA, it works!

scores.select(:source).distinct
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Score id: nil, source: "Telegraph">, #<Score id: nil, source: "Mail">, #<Score id: nil, source: "Independent">, #<Score id: nil, source: "Express">, #<Score id: nil, source: "Guardian">]>

        #oops, no it doesn't
```

Comment: So what's the result set you want?

Comment: I am using it to try to get back an array of complete objects, not just a particular field.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 distinct has no parameter. In Rails 4.2 the parameter is only `true` or `false`. When `true`, return distinct records, when `false` return none distinct records. `uniq` is in this case only an alias for `distinct`

So for Rails 4

`scores.select(:source).distinct.count` is what you want. This restricts `distinct` to column `source`

Comment: But it will not return full objects, will it?

Comment: `scores.select(:source).distinct` does not return full objects. Only objects with filled source columns. Because you can't say which values you want for the other attributes. For instance the object with the `source` Mail which value should have `created_at`? The value of record 123 or the other?

Comment: So how do I get back all the Score objects with unique :source attribute?

Comment: For your example you want all score objects except the objects with source `Mail`? Or do you want all score objects including the first or last object with source `Mail`?